# Intent object instantiation parameters

Tags: android, android-intent

In android, when instantiating `Intent` object, it takes two parameters: `currentClassName.this` and `targetClassName.class`

Those two parameters : 
1)how they are obtained? 
2)Are they a predefined objects or something?

Answer (score 1):

[`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is the current object, and since you need to pass context to the intent, you take the `this` of the enclosing class, it is done by specifying the fully qualified name: `TheEnclosingClass.this`

[`class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is an object that represent the type of class, so `TargetClassName.class` is the type of the class `TargetClassName`. It is passed since the class type is needed for instantiating the new class (by reflection).

Comment: if `this` and `class` are objects, why they are used here as properties: `TheEnclosingclass.this`  and `TargetClassName.class` .. from this context I understood that the object here are `TargetClassName` that has a property `class` , and `TheEnclosingClass` that has a `this` property..hence where did those two objects `TheEnclosingClass` and `TargetClassName` came from??

Comment: When you have a class inside a class, `this` refers to the most inner class, to refer  to the enclosing type, you need to fully qualify `this`

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent( currentClassName.this,targetClassName.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("selectID",valuse);
startActivity(intent);
```

intent.putExtra("selectID",valuse); to pass some values in other class